# SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user in shared hosting

Tags: php, laravel

I'm setting up a laravel project to shared hosting. I've followed the way to upload laravel project to shared hosting, it run well but I have problem in database connection.

> Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (1045)
>   SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'havanah_havyblog'@'xxxxx.xxxxxx.id' (using password: YES) (SQL: insert into `laravel_logger_activity` (`description`, `userType`, `userId`, `route`, `ipAddress`, `userAgent`, `locale`, `referer`, `methodType`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Viewed /, Guest, ?, https://havyblog.havanah.id/laravel/public, xxx.xxx.xx.xxx, Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.131 Safari/537.36, en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8, https://www.xxxxx.id/havyblog/laravel/, GET, 2019-05-09 02:02:19, 2019-05-09 02:02:19))

This is my .env

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=153.xx.x.xxx
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=havanah_havyblog
DB_USERNAME=havanah_havyblog
DB_PASSWORD=xxxxxx
```

Im sure the password is correct.

And this is my db
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bwKT.png)

And I've followed too the resolving method by using config:clear, but it had not been resolved yet.

Comment: havanah_havyblog@153.11.1.111 is not necessarily the same user as havanah_havyblog@whateverdomain.id.

Comment: Have you tried connecting with MySQL workbench or another tool that will confirm your username/domain/password/database name are all correct?

Comment: Oh I see, ok I'll try your suggestion sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add the user **havanah_havyblog** to Database **havanah_havyblog**, and give it all priveleges, also set the `DB_HOST=localhost`. 
Cpanel > Databases > Add User to Database

Comment: But new issue comes that the front end doesn't work, how should I do?

Comment: when you importing your assets like css, can you wrap them inside `asset()` helper like this src=`{{asset('public')}}/css/style.css`

Comment: I'll try your suggestion sir

Comment: Add `{{asset('public')}}` after all your `<script src="` and `<link href="`

Comment: I've fixed this problem sir, thanks for your help _/|\_